# How to selectively refresh a resource (ie. javascript source) from Chrome/Chromium Developer Tools without reloading the whole webpage

Tags: google-chrome, web, chromium

For debug purposes, I need to refresh only a part of a webpage (ie. javascript sources).

The only partial solution I found is, where jQuery is already present, to use a shorthand function from jQuery framework: [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

From Chromium Developer Tools' Console typing:

```
$.getScript('http://resource_to_refresh.js');
```

But in this way, the scripts tab is not updated.

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks